# load javascript via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm loading the following code via javascript into the website via ajax request:

```
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        <?php
            echo $this->Html->script('pdfobject');
        ?>
        <div id="showdoc" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; /*border: 1px solid black;*/">
            <p><?php echo __('It appears you don\'t have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser. ').$this->Html->link(__('Click here to download the file'), array('action' => 'getFile', '?' => array('id' => $data['Voucher']['id'], 'download' => true)), array()); ?></p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function (){
                var myPDF = new PDFObject({         
                    url: "<?php
                        echo $this->Html->url(
                            array(
                                'controller' => 'vouchers',
                                'action' => 'getFile',
                                '?' => array(
                                    'id' => $data['Voucher']['id']
                                    //'download' => 'true'
                                )
                            ),
                            true

                        );
                    ?>",
                pdfOpenParams: {
                    navpanes: 0,
                    toolbar: 0,
                    statusbar: 0,
                    view: 'FitBH,0',//'FitH,0', "FitV"
                    scrollbars: '1',
                    messages: '0'
                    }
                }).embed("showdoc");
            };
        </script>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, the code is not executed. If I call the php file with this code via browser directly, everything works fine.
I expect the problem is, that the code is not executed because the base page is already loaded. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: When you ajax js, you (usually) get the text for the js. So you need to 'evaluate' the code to run it. Since usage of 'eval' can be evil in some cases, I'd advice to write the script code in a seperate file, and then create a script tag with the src set to the path of the external file. When you insert the script tag into the body, it will automatically fetch the script and run it, no explicit ajax call to the script needed. It won't run any window.onload events though, since the window was already loaded before you did an ajax call. If its to use in iframe or new tab, just use a hyperlink.

Comment: Thank you Shilly. I understand now that I have to use evaluate. But how do I execute the code after loading? Does something work like $('#showdoc').onload ?

Comment: Don't use eval for this kind of things. Can you explain what you mean by 'loading the following code via javascript into the website via ajax request'. Since if this is just a part of a page when you insert the 'showdoc' div after ajaxing the html string, you can just move all the JS to the function that makes that ajax call no?

Comment: The above code (whole code) is loaded by ajax into a modal (bootstrap modal). And this code above loads a pdf-file into the modal.
Alternatively I could load the url variable via ajax and refresh the function some how.

Comment: Why don't you just run the javascript in the main function that makes the ajax call and inserts the html into the modal? Any reason why the extra pdf javascript has to be inside the html you ajax? But grats that it works now with the url.

Comment: Sometimes I think to far but the solution is rather easy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shilly. I loaded the var `url` itself, without ajax. Everything works fine.